# Why can I not instatiate a new Frame object in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an interactive graph that is displayed in the Tkinter window. However, I am not able to create a Frame object to place in the Grid of the Tkinter window.

I have created my Tkinter object in a class style here is the instantiation of it

```
window = Tk()
w = Graph(window, size, startX, startY, endX, endY)
window.geometry('1000x1000')
window.title('Tkinter Testing')
window.mainloop()
```

I am referring to this tutorial: [Tkinter Geometry Manager](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#the-pack-geometry-manager)

```
for x in range(len(self.graph)):
    for y in range(len(self.graph[0])):
        frame = window.Frame(
            master=window,
            relief=window.RAISED,
            borderwidth=1
        )
        frame.grid(row=x,column=y)
        label = window.Label(master = frame, text="testing")
```

This is the error thrown in the console

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Graph.py", line 158, in <module>
    w = Graph(window, size, startX, startY, endX, endY)
  File "Graph.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.displayGraph()
  File "Graph.py", line 39, in displayGraph
    frame = window.Frame(
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1909, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: Frame
```

Comment: Did you mean ‘Frame(...’ or ‘tk.Frame(...’?

Comment: Also, you're calling `.grid()` on the window instead of the Frame, so none of your Frames will actually appear.

Comment: @quamrana when I call  `frame = window.tk.Frame()` it throws the same error.

Comment: @jasonharper I updated the question and the code in my IDE, thanks. Based on that logic, the Label object is also declared incorrectly, in the tutorial, it uses `tk.Label` however I cannot instantiate my Tkinter object as `window = tk.Tk()`.

Comment: If you did `import tkinter as tk`, you could say things like `tk.Tk()` or `tk.Label()`.  If you did `from tkinter import *`, you would instead have to say `Tk()` or `Label()` (this option is generally not recommended, since it's no longer obvious where the definitions of these names are coming from).

Comment: I doubt that `frame = window.tk.Frame()` throws *exactly* the same error. Anyway, did you try `frame = Frame(...`?

Comment: Err... @jsonharper has already explained all this. Perhaps you need to update the question with your `import` statements for `tkinter`.

Comment: @quamrana I apologize for my ignorance. Thanks a ton for this help. The issue with the import statement is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @quamarana and @jasonharper for shedding light and explaining the issue.

The answer to this question had to do with how Tkinter is imported. The syntax when instantiating an object is slightly different based on the import statement.

`import tkinter as tk` or `from tkinter import Tk`

```
button = tk.Button(...
frame = tk.Frame(...
label = tk.Label(...
```

`from tkinter import *`

```
button = Button(...
frame = Frame(...
label = Label(...
```

As @jasonharper pointed out:

> If you did from tkinter import *, you would instead have to say Tk() or Label() (this option is generally not recommended, since it's no longer obvious where the definitions of these names are coming from).